# How to integrate sliding pannel control used in Twitter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

I want to Integrate Sliding Panel Control Like used in Twitter so i can i integrate it.Give me some idea and Sample code if anybody integrate it.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://petersteinberger.com/2010/01/tweetie-like-swipe-menu-for-iphone-apps/

The download link for the code is broken but these blogs should help you.

Comment: Do you have any other sample code sites or blogs which gives any sample code or can you help me via sample code.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, here our is a demo project which is inspired by Twitter-ipad app

> http://www.raweng.com/blog/stack-scroll-view/

source code is opensource on githib (link posted in above blog).

hope that help you to understand the concept behind it !!